# Сериализация и запись в файл

Tags: php

Есть два PHP файла. Оба файла содержат класс, в котором есть метод сериализации массива и записи в файл.

```
var_dump(
    file_put_contents(
        'store',
        'serialize($this->files)',
        LOCK_EX | FILE_APPEND
    )
);
```

Оба файла выводят `int(23)` но записывает в файл только один.

Права доступа на все три файла `777` (третий - `store`)
В логе ошибок нет.

Что это может быть и как это исправить?

Comment: Вы двумя скриптами пытаетесь одновременно записывать в один файл?

Comment: @AntonioK, нет, они не зупускаются одновременно.

Comment: почему в кавычках то? Что без  LOCK_EX?